# How to set a field editable only for a group? In odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In hr attendances, there is a field called "employee_id".

I want to set this field editable only for a group (or set readonly for other groups).

For example, I want to set the field "employee_id" editable in the "form" view only for the "manager" group.

I have extended the attendance module and I have this code in the XML of my extended module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
    <record id="view_employee_readonly_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.attendance.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.attendance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_attendance.view_attendance_form"/>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6,0,[ref('base.group_hr_manager')])]"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="employee_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

With this code, the field is editable for everyone EXCEPT for the hr_manager group. That is the opposite that I want.

What I have to modify in order to achieve this?

Edited: I have modified the original code with a different field to better understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it!

## First, the field has to be defined as readonly for everyone.

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_id']" position="replace">
     <field name="employee_id" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
</xpath>
```

## Then, we inherit the first custom view

```xml
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_attendance_extend.view_employee_readonly_custom"/>
```

## Finally, we delete the readonly restriction for the administrators group (group_hr_manager)

```xml
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_hr_manager')])]"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_id']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="readonly">False</attribute>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

## Here is the final code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
    <record id="view_employee_readonly_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.attendance.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.attendance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_attendance.view_attendance_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="employee_id" attrs="{'readonly':True}"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_employee_readonly" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.attendance.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.attendance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_attendance_extend.view_employee_readonly_custom" />
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_hr_manager')])]"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='employee_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="readonly">False</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, there is no built-in way in Odoo to make a field editable for a certain group only.

You can make it visible or invisible by adding a group to it.

If you DO want to make the field editable depending on a group, you will need to create a new computed field that is user-dependent, and add an attrs on the field to make it readonly based on the user.

In your case, you would need something like this:

In python:

```
can_edit_name = fields.Boolean(compute='_compute_can_edit_name')

def _compute_can_edit_name(self):
  self.can_edit_name = self.env.user.has_group('base.group_hr_user')
```

In your xml :

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="before">
  <field name="can_edit_name" invisible="1"/>
</xpath>

<xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('can_edit_name', '!=', True)]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

This means that if the can_edit_name is True, the field will  be editable.

I haven't tested it so there may be some typos, but this should give you an idea of how to do it !

Good luck !

Comment: I don't want to use a computed field. Now, I have found the solution. Anyway, thanks for the answer :)